# Different viewport width for the same page in the same browser

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, viewport

If I open a page directly from filesystem browser reports different viewport width then if I serve it with simple python web server. Also, the viewport is the same in another browser (tested Safari and Firefox). Because of the reported larger width, my content is more squeezed. Why is there a difference for the same file?

There is this meta tag set on that page

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
```

Here is the recording of the reported behavior http://recordit.co/aWwJzXxEvS

Comment: Screenshots don't help; not even animated ones. You should know that by now. We need a [mcve], or if you can't produce one for some reason, at least a link to the live page.

Comment: @MrLister The problem is that I experience the problem locally on different webservers. For example, if I download https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/narrow-jumbotron/ (save as in Chrome) and then serve that page with "python -m SimpleHTTPServer" or "http-server" (node package) I get respectively 2100 and 1680 pixel width viewports and that is just in Chrome, FireFox and Safari both have 1680 on both servers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after trying everything under the Sun, I figured it out.

Opening the page as `localhost:port` messes up the viewport in Chrome, it obviously uses some different logic for websites that it deems local or whatever.

But opening the page on the same local server with `127.0.0.1:port` works as expected.